# SWT - Snap display to right hand side of the screen

Tags: java, swt

I'm creating an SWT application and have been unsuccessfully searching around on the net for a way to snap my window to the right of the screen (in a similar fashion to the way google desktop  used to work).

So if the start menu is on the right hand side of the screen it should sit to the left of it otherwise it can snap directly to the right hand side of the screen.

Can anyone help me out with a way that I can do this?

Comment: Why the Swing tag when your question has nothing to do with Swing?

Comment: I thought someone may have a swing alternative... Sorry

Comment: @user1600419 Any feedback on my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'll be giving this a shot in the next couple of days. Thks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that utilizes the functions found by sambi:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.VERTICAL));
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");

    Monitor primary = display.getPrimaryMonitor();

        /* Get the available screen size (without start menu) */
    Rectangle area = primary.getClientArea();

    shell.pack();
    /* Set the shell size */
    shell.setBounds(area.x + area.width / 2, area.y, area.width / 2, area.height);
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Tested on both Linux (panel left and bottom) and Windows 7 (start menu left).

Answer (score 3):

Use below methods to set bounds on your main shell.

```
org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display

public Monitor [] getMonitors ()

public Monitor getPrimaryMonitor ()
```