# Screen Docking in swing using JWindow

Tags: java, swing, awt, jwindow

I am using `JWindow` to develop a bar which will appear on the top of the screen. The issue is that I want to dock it onto the screen and every other application should come under that. Currently the `close` and `maximize` buttons are going behind my application.

I have done some research, but I am unable to get it to work.

[This question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391726/swt-snap-display-to-right-hand-side-of-the-screen) answer gives me the idea but it doesn't really do what I want.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with Java/Swing/AWT

Comment: have look at JToolBar, never tried undecorated

Comment: @MadProgrammer please let me know how can i achieve that

Comment: @mKorbel Jtoolbar is for within application usage

Comment: You're either going have to switch to SWT (as that tool kit seems to have a solution) or find a native solution via JNI/JNA